# Access By Term(abt) is not work in SOLR search Drupal 7

Tags: nodes, search, taxonomy-terms

I'm using [Access By Term](https://www.drupal.org/project/abt) contrib module which is used for show the node when the node term reference and the user term reference is equal. I can get this, Also in solr search, **Filter** tab setting I have enabled the **Node access** checkbox. However when I'm searching the particular node title with other user credentials, actuallay the other user cannot be able to search those nodes. Still solr search resulting a node. I want to restrict this??? Is there any way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. If the Solr server want to obey node access means, we must index the **Status** and **Author** field to the server. I have done this, now the node access is perfectly worked even with the search also.